# How to click on ::before / ::after CC tag in selenium webdriver with Python?

Tags: python, selenium

Working on Selenium testing. Need to click on ::before tag for drag and drop.

Below is the inspect element screenshot:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50dRW.png)

I tried this way, but couldn't help.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("""driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span.ag-icon ag-icon-grip ag-column-drag").perform()""")
```

How to achieve xpath of that element to do operation.

Comment: adding image of code is bad practice and question end up with less attention, please add html code of element you have problem with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to click on the [::before](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before) element as it's not supposed to be clicked/clickable.

My expectation is that you need to click the associated [`<span>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span) which in its turn can be located using the following expression:

```
//span[text()='PM Team']
```

I cannot see the DOM fully, it might be the case you will have to go for [XPath contains() function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span) like:

```
//span[contains(text(), 'PM Team')]
```